# Implicit Differentiation of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find $\;\dfrac{\partial z }{\partial x},\,\dfrac{\partial z }{\partial y}\;$ of $\;x^3+y^3+z^3=R^3$.

For $\dfrac{\partial z }{\partial x}\,$ it is

\begin{align}
3x^2+3z^2\cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= 3R^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} 
&\implies&&&
3z^2\cdot\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}-3R^2 \frac{\partial z }{\partial x}=3x^2
\\ &&\implies&&&
\big(3z^2-3R^2\big)\frac{\partial z }{\partial x} = 3x^2 
\\&&\implies &&&
\frac{\partial z }{\partial x} = \frac{3x^2}{3z^2-3R^2}
\end{align}

and for $\,\dfrac{\partial z }{\partial y}\,$ it is in the same way
$$\frac{\partial z }{\partial y}=\frac{3y^2}{3z^2-3R^2}$$

How do I treat $R$?
Is it a function of $z$ and therefore I need to differentiate it with respect to $z$ which is differentiated with respect to $x$ or $y$?

Comment: May be, $dy/dz$?

Comment: $R$ is a constant. Or, you could say that your equation is $F(x,y,z)=0$ where $F(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3-R^3$, so when you calculate derivatives, the $R^3$ term vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

If $R(z)$ is a function of $z$ than:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(
R^3(z)
\right)=3R^2(z)\frac{d R}{d z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
$$

and analogously for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(
R^3(z) \right)$, so the  final result becomes more complex and you must know the form of the function $R(z)$ to proceed.

But I suppose that in your problem $R$ is a constant so all is more easy.